# Ionic2 and Facebook Login: Errors in emulating android device after installing cordova-plugin-facebook4

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, plugins, ionic2

I have an Ionic2 app that I was hoping to install cordova-plugin-facebook4 with and setup Facebook Login. I've followed a few tutorials like this one [here](http://tphangout.com/using-facebook-graph-api-in-your-ionic-2-apps/) but I am running into issues when I try to emulate an android build.

Here is the error message:

```
Error: /Users/mreiter/documents/photor/photor/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
         :android:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.jar
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.pom
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.jar
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.pom
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.jar
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
         :android:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/customtabs/23.4.0/customtabs-23.4.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/customtabs/23.4.0/customtabs-23.4.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/23.4.0/customtabs-23.4.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/23.4.0/customtabs-23.4.0.jar
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.4.0/customtabs-23.4.0.pom
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.4.0/customtabs-23.4.0.jar
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.4.0/customtabs-23.4.0.pom
         file:/Users/mreiter/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.4.0/customtabs-23.4.0.jar
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
         :android:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experiencing this issue this morning.  The following steps worked for me:

1. Started a clean Ionic 2 project
2. Added android platform & installed the ionic facebook wrapper as described in the docs.
3. Opened Android Studio, imported the project from platforms/android/
4. Let it load, but when it asks you to update Gradle select ignore for this project.

After that it'll 'strongly recommend' you to update Gradle, once again ignore it and it'll Android Studio will start running your Gradle and building out an APK.

You'll find that you can use `ionic build android` and it should work.

Also I removed all Android SDK's except Android 6.X.X (Marshmallow).  Give it a try.  Still not exactly sure what the issue was though.